# retrieve image from database blob data type

Tags: java, activejdbc, javalite

Good day sir, I'm having trouble in deploying image from database with a blob datatype. I tried path and it's working good. Now I want to try out Blob but I'm having trouble what code will I use.
thanks in advance sir

[database image value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJmWS.png) 
.

here's the code.

```
List<rec_item_med> recitemmed = new rec_item_med().findAll();

for (rec_item_med l : recitemmed){
    File file = new File("C:\\ecommerce\\first_ecom\\webcontent\\images\\items\\"+l.getString("No")+".png");
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    byte[] bytes = l.getBytes("picture");
    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    while (inputStream.read(b) > 0) {
        fileOutputStream.write(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include your  code and exceptions if any

Comment: So you want to retreive blob content from database...?

Comment: absolutely right

Comment: @kuya, you are not providing any information that may help. I certainly used ActiveJDBC to store images and even PDFs before.

Comment: @ipolevoy, My bad sorry for that. anyway I solved it already but is there any other way to store and retrieve image via active jdbc?
here is what I did. (edited)

Comment: I had to format your code to read it, and you were also missing a brace. I still do not understand if this is a problem or a question.